# Raspberry Pi 0 W spontaneous event triggering for an input pin

Tags: python-3, rpio

I have two "Cylewet 25Pcs AC 1A 125V 3Pin SPDT Limit Micro Switch"-es that are normally open and connected to two of the Pi pins with internal pull up resistors.
Left unattended, they call spontaneously the registered function as though they were pressed. What could be the reason for that?
Here is the important part of the code:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def func(channel: int):
    ...
    log.debug('The end breaker is pressed - channel %i', channel)

GPIO.setup([18,19], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=func)
GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.FALLING, callback=func)
```

Here is the log:

```
2019-10-26 14:10:03,982 INFO     last activity
2019-10-26 16:46:21,676 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 18
2019-10-26 16:46:21,681 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 18
2019-10-26 16:46:21,688 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 19
```

Comment: How long are the cables connecting the switches?

Comment: Wrong GPIO being used, poor wiring, floating inputs.  Any number of reasons.  A clear photo may help.

Comment: You have big EMI (Electro Magnetic Interference) equipment such as heavy duty air conditioner, high power induction cooker, etc near by, or crossing your very long GPIO connecting wires, which like an antenna, picking up all sorts of 200VAC mains noise/spikes, motor/transformer (induction cooker has a big transformer) EMI spikes (my flats mains/mini circuit breaker has aged, and from time to time radiates spikes along the power line and to the wall wart, causing intermittent disturbances to the WinPC, / to continue, ...

Comment: / ... and in worst cases, not just flickering, but even resetting my PC and Rpi.  I have a "ground floating" scope to screen capture the fluctuating mains power and report to the power company.  Finally the electrician came and replaced the aging MCB with a new one, and all push buttons etc become good guys again.  Of it is just my intermittent power related weird button story, your push buttons might be excited by other things, ...

Comment: The wires are less than 50cm. I've added the GPIO bouncetime (100ms) and left it for a day - channel 18 that was firing twice in 5ms have registered two single logs (hours apart). I'll try to introduce an RC group close to the pins, but I have a feeling it is something internal or the wires from the two switches that run in parallel would have registered same number of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions! I have replaced the wires with shielded audio cables and also connected the Pi pins thru the following circuit and I do not see the spontaneous events anymore:

```
                          o +3.3V 
                          | 
                         --- 
                         /_\ 
                          | 
                  10k     |            220
                  _____   |           _____ 
              o--|_____|--+------+---|_____|--o Pi pin 
                          |      | 
shielded wires           ---     | 
from the switch          /_\   ===== 100n
                          |      |
              o-----------+------+------------o
                          |
                         ---
                          -
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.